# Glib: meson.build:1317:23: ERROR: lexer

Tags: glib

New to ubuntu. No idea what this error means. Please help.

```
mgrl@mgrl-System-Product-Name:~/glib-2.63.3$ meson _build
The Meson build system
Version: 0.45.1
Source dir: /home/mgrl/glib-2.63.3
Build dir: /home/mgrl/glib-2.63.3/_build
Build type: native build

meson.build:1317:23: ERROR: lexer
g_sizet_compatibility = {
                       ^
```

Comment: This is some error when trying to build some software.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to rectify this.

Comment: I have no idea what are you trying to build and what is your system.

Comment: System: 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu, x86_64 GNU/Linux; Trying to install Glib.

Comment: Do you need Glib 2.63 specifically? why are you not simply installing binary glib-2.0 package(s) from the repository?

Comment: Same error with Kubuntu 5.1 kernel version